# How to check if database exist on Remote Server through SQL query

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a table as following in SQL Server 2012.

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      ClientName     |     servername   |Databasename      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          c1         |         s1       |         b1       |
|          c2         |         s2       |         b2       |
|          c3         |         s4       |         b4       |
|          c4         |         s5       |         b6       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Is there a way to return only rows for which  database exists on the server names mentioned in the table?

I searched in forums for the answer but couldn't get one. I am aware that there exists a query as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22182437/check-if-table-exists-in-external-linked-database) which checks whether database on that server exists or not. *But in my case, I want it to be part of where clause.*

***Also, please consider that, this table is in server 1 but the servers in table can be different from each other.***
*(Although I have posted this question on Stackoverflow, but thought to post in this forum too. I am looking for quick answer but I haven't got one.)*